# Ctrl+v pastes in the terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, vim

when I am in vim and want to use `Crtl`+`v` to go to the visual mode it pastes text I copied. How can I disable that?

Comment: You can edit your `vimrc` to achieve this, im not 100% sure of what you would need but thats the direction you need to be heading in.

Comment: problem is that this also happens in the normal terminal

Comment: Change the keybinding in your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

found this snippet that worked:

`gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings natural-copy-paste false`

on this website:

https://elementaryforums.com/index.php?threads/configuring-shortcuts-in-the-pantheon-terminal.2067/